# vim java omnicomplete

Tags: java, vim, omnicomplete

I'm doing my best to follow the directions for install here: http://vim.sourceforge.net/scripts/script.php?script_id=1785, but I can't get it working and it seems sort of vague.

Here's what I've done.

- I verified that I've got vim 7 or higher.
- I created a $HOME/.vim directory
- I unzipped the latest into $HOME/.vim
- I added the following two lines to .vimrc:

---

```
:setlocal omnifunc=javacomplete#Complete
:setlocal completefunc=javacomplete#CompleteParamsInfo
```

From there I'm not sure what I'm supposed to do to get it working. Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `:setlocal` command set only the value for the current buffer and it makes no difference inside `.vimrc`. Instead, you should tell vim to set the value for every file of type `java`. This is how it is done:

```
if has("autocmd")
  autocmd Filetype java setlocal omnifunc=javacomplete#Complete
  autocmd Filetype java setlocal completefunc=javacomplete#CompleteParamsInfo
endif
```

Replace the commands in your `.vimrc` with the lines above and reload it (you can run `:source ~/.vimrc` for that).

Notice that you need `autocmd` for that (you must observe the value `1` when running `:echo has("autocmd")` inside vim).

Comment: Why `:execute "echo has('autocmd')"` and not `:echo has('autocmd')`?

Comment: ops... yeah, you are right. I've just tried only `:has("autocmd")` first and had no answer and I tought it was because the `has(string)` function worked only inside scripts. I will edit the answer.. thanks

Comment: Ok, and then what is the escape sequence to get auto-complete going?

Comment: Ok so I've noticed that CTRL-P causes auto completion to happen. Honestly it's a bit underwhelming, since it only seems to match symbols that have already been declared in the same file. I.e. if I do "private InputStream is = new Bu<CTRL-P>" it doesn't know what to do because I haven't explicitly imported BufferedInputStream yet. Even if I do java.io.Bu<CTRL-P> it still is clueless. Is this really all this thing does?

Comment: `<C-X><C-O>` should do the job